# Flutter doctor unhandled exception

Tags: flutter, unhandled-exception

I was trying to use flutter.
Each time I execute the flutter command, this exception is being thrown

I guess, the problem is because of space in my user profile name.
But other applications work fine without any problem.

```
ProcessException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
Command: C:\Users\Chirag Rawal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

their is a space in your user folder("Chirag Rawal"). avoid that space and it will work fine.

for more look at this git hub issue.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18938

i hope this video help you out to change folder name.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_rTOA4gXJI

Comment: Yes, I had to rename it so that there is no space in that.
Now it's working fine.
Thanks.